# How to implicitly convert cpp type within a context of a class?

Tags: c++

I have some variants of length, which can take actual value only in context.

In the example below we can define length in pixels, points or em's, each with its context specific conversion.

Is there a way to make the `to_double()` function implicit?

(code edited to clarify the question)

It is easy to do this globally (using global variables - blah..) , but I can't figure out how to do this in context.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Length_pixels { double val; };
struct Length_points { double val; };
struct Length_em { double val; };
inline Length_pixels operator "" _px(long double d) { return Length_pixels{ (double)d }; }
inline Length_points operator "" _pt(long double d) { return Length_points{ (double)d }; }
inline Length_em     operator "" _em(long double d) { return Length_em{ (double)d }; }

struct Context {
    // this context uses pixels and has its own definition of DPI and em
    double points_to_pixels = 0.5; 
    double em_to_pixels = 20;

    inline double to_double(const Length_pixels &v) { return v.val ; }
    inline double to_double(const Length_points &v) { return v.val * points_to_pixels; }
    inline double to_double(const Length_em &v) { return v.val * em_to_pixels; }
    
    double x = to_double(10.0_pt);
    double y = to_double(4.7_em);

    // this could be a nice syntax for implicit - but it does not compile  
    inline implicit operator double(const Length_points &v) const { 
        return v.val * points_to_pixels; 
    }
    // so this would work:
    double z = 10.0_pt;

    
};

using namespace std;
int main() {
    Context c;
    cout << c.x << ", " << c.y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbec3a03549fc05a

Comment: What do you mean by "implicit", specifically?

Comment: You can get implicit conversion by defining `operator double()` for each of your `Length_xxx` classes, but in this case it's not really clear what behavior you want to be implicit. Maybe your `Context` should define a constructor template allowing any combination of `Length_xxx` type. Or something like this.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://godbolt.org/z/4jTMqEboa) is what you're trying to achieve? I can't understand your reasons for storing `x` and `y` in `Context` because that class is clearly used to do specific translation to pixels. So just defining an operator or a member function to convert a value within that context is _probably_ what you want.

Comment: Please see edits above - hope it is clearer. basically I would like 'double z = 10.0_pt;' to work according to the relevant context.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking some inspiration from the chrono lib for this. A very reduced and untested example of what I mean:

```cpp
enum class LengthType {
    Pixels, Em, Points
};
template<LengthType Type>
struct Length
{
    double value;
};
template<LengthType Type>
Length<Type> operator+(Length<Type> const& left, Length<Type> const& right) {... }
// operators -, *, /, ...
```

```cpp
namespace my_context {

using Points = Length<LengthType::Points>;

struct Pixels : public Length<LengthType::Pixels>
{
    static constexpr double to_points = 2.0;
    operator Points() const {return Points{.value = value * to_points};} 

    Pixels(Points const& pts) {value = pts.value / to_points;} 
};

}
```

Defining them this way allows you to directly add, subtract, etc instances of your lengths. And you can make all types in my_context implicitly convertible into each other.

Comment: Assume 'double to_points' is not cont, it may be passed in a constructor or even be set in a setup function. And it is not a property of the pixels but of, say, the screen. Which would be the context.

Comment: Do you deal with multiple contexts at the same time?

Comment: Yes. Contexts may coexist. Possibly multi-threaded. Need to avoid global variables.

Comment: And I assume you don't just have a few set contexts known at compile time, but rather an unspecified number of dynamic contexts known only at runtime?

Comment: The parameters may be passed in a constructor or even be set in a setup function.

Comment: In that case build screenpixels, screenpoints etc that take the context in the constructor and use that to implement conversion functions. It doesn't have to be const.